# Multiple Project MSI Installer not running after install

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I am working on a project with multiple projects in it and I need to add an msi installer. I have been using tutorials to setup a standard msi and an msi with custom actions so far. At the moment, I get my .msi file in the release folder but when I install it and then try to run it, nothing happens.

The one main project is set to the primary project output since that is where the executable is created. I've also tried to add the primary project output to the custom action to see if it would help but nothing new happened.

I do get the correct file structure in the program files but the program does not run. Any ideas??

Comment: The installer itself doesn't run, or the application that it installs?

Comment: The application that it installs doesn't run and not sure why.

Comment: If you build the application locally, navigate to the folder with the executable and start it up, does it run? If so, first place I'd look is some a missing dll. You can also look in the event viewer to see if there's any information on the crash. Try adding some exception handling/logging to your applications Program.cs file.

Comment: Well, I have 4 projects in the solution and yes it runs from the solution folder. Then when I add the executable as primary output it detects the other 3 projects as dependencies. So everything seems ok but it doesn't run. But if I copy the executable back to the project solution, the program runs but it will not run from the programs folder in Program Files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Anna, that was a good hint. There was a new config file that was added to the project that was messing things up. After I deleted it and debugged it I found the culprit to be a bug in my fellow developer's code. After that was fixed I was able to create the msi and run the program after install. Thanks for your help.